# React wrapper component (HOC) does not re-render child component when it's props are changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

My wrapper component has this signature

```
const withReplacement = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  (props: P & WithReplacementProps) => {...}
```

Btw, full example is here https://codepen.io/xitroff/pen/BaKQNed

It's getting original content from argument component's props

```
interface WithReplacementProps {
  getContent(): string;
}
```

and then call `setContent` function on button click.

```
const { getContent, ...rest } = props;
const [ content, setContent ] = useState(getContent());
```

I expect that content will be replaced everywhere (1st and 2nd section below).
Here's the part of render function

```
return (
      <>
        <div>
          <h4>content from child</h4>
          <Component
            content={content}
            ReplaceButton={ReplaceButton}
            {...rest as P}
          />
          <hr/>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4>content from wrapper</h4>
          <Hello
            content={content}
            ReplaceButton={ReplaceButton}
          />
          <hr/>
        </div>
      </>
    );
```

Hello component is straightforward

```
<div>
  <p>{content}</p>
  <div>
    {ReplaceButton}
  </div>
</div>
```

and that's how wrapped is being made

```
const HelloWithReplacement = withReplacement(Hello);
```

But the problem is that content is being replaced only in 2nd part. 1st remains untouched.

In the main App component I also replace the content after 20 sec from loading.

```
const [ content, setContent ] = useState( 'original content');

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setContent('...too late! replaced from main component');
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
```

...when I call my wrapped component like this

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <HelloWithReplacement
        content={content}
        getContent={() => content}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

And it also has the issue - 1st part is updating, 2nd part does not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overriding the `withReplacement` internal state with the external state of the App

```
<HelloWithReplacement
    content={content} // Remove this to stop overriding it
    getContent={() => content}
  />
```

Anyway it looks weird to use two different states, it is better to manage your app state in only one place

Comment: I don’t need to update the state in two places. I need just 2 things: 1) get content from argument component 2) replace it inside argument component by action inside wrapper. The rest was added for debugging and explanation purposes. And yes, it looks weird, but shows the concrete issue. If you can achieve this by removing “debug” things, that’d be perfect :)

Comment: Did you try removing the content prop from `HelloWithReplacement`?

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue, here’s short example without a fix btw https://codepen.io/xitroff/pen/bGpBVPz